# Percona system tables corrupted

Tags: replication

I am having problems setting up mysql replication with a percona as server. accidentally, took a full dump from mysql and restored it on percona and then started,the replication. now when i stop slave and start slave, i am getting the error "[ERROR] Failed to open the relay log './s5-bin.000003' (relay_log_pos 2029993)
110103  9:15:59 [ERROR] Could not find target log during relay log initialization
"
But show local variables shows the relay_log variable as set in the cnf file..

But the relay-log variable is set to slave-relay-bin alright. I am able to start mysql as a service. But mysqld_safe fails with error "110103  9:19:39 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid' (Errcode: 2)
110103  9:19:39 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No such file or directory
"

Am now lost as to what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "Can't create/write to file '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid'" looks like a permissions problem. Please make sure that the directory /var/run/mysqld belongs to the user 'mysql'.